# Jsoup - nextElementSibling() usage

Tags: java, html, jsoup

i am stuck with a problem, here is the html code,

```
<p>
<span class="jadd"></span>
<span>No # 1 / a,&nbsp;Near GANESH temple ,&nbsp; Jp NAGARa Jp nagar 8 phase kothanurdinne     ,&nbsp;Jp Nagar 7th Phase,&nbsp;Bangalore - 560078</span>
</p>
```

i am finding the

```
<span class="jadd"></span>
```

line with jsoup's getElementByClass() function. but now i want the information that is in the next tag to where i am bumped into now , i mean i want this

```
<span>No # 1 / a,&nbsp;Near GANESH temple ,&nbsp; Jp NAGARa Jp nagar 8 phase kothanurdinne     ,&nbsp;Jp Nagar 7th Phase,&nbsp;Bangalore - 560078</span>
```

i need to extract the data from the above tag. how will i navigate to this after using a code like this,

```
Elements address = doc.getElementsByClass("jadd");
```

after googling a bit, i found out the function `nextElementSibling()` of Jsoup might be helpful to me. but i do not know how to use this in this scenario. please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through the elements and get the siblings for each element

```
for ( Element el : doc.getElementsByClass("jadd") ) {
  Element sibling = el.nextElementSibling();
  // get sibling content
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to fix your code from:

```
<p>
<span class="jadd"></span>
<span>No # 1 / a,&nbsp;Near GANESH temple ,&nbsp; Jp NAGARa Jp nagar 8 phase kothanurdinne     ,&nbsp;Jp Nagar 7th Phase,&nbsp;Bangalore - 560078</span>
</p>
```

To:

```
<p>
<span class="jadd">
<span>No # 1 / a,&nbsp;Near GANESH temple ,&nbsp; Jp NAGARa Jp nagar 8 phase kothanurdinne     ,&nbsp;Jp Nagar 7th Phase,&nbsp;Bangalore - 560078</span>
</span>
</p>
```

And also change:

```
Element address = doc.select("span.jadd > span").first();
```